pound sign is not displaying correctly (showing like "xA3") in xml file generated from java in notepad++
I am generating one xml file from java code where currency symbol "£" is showing as xA3 in notepad++ and showing correctly in notepad. Encoding for the file is defined as UTF-8. If i copy the same symbol "xA3" and paste in same file somethere it shows correctly.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataExtract xmlns:vltrdr="........." xsi:schemaLocation="D:\Apps\Test\schema/Test.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
<header>
  <creationDateTime>2024-04-10T06:47:15</creationDateTime>
  <reference>A_20240410064715</reference>
</header>
<letters>
<letter>
        <reportingCurrency>GBP</reportingCurrency>
        <reportingCurrencySymbol>GB£</reportingCurrencySymbol>
  </letter>
</letters>

</DataExtract>

what should be done so that it shows correctly in Notepad++ as well?
Updated: Also, this is working perfectly fine on the local system but not working correctly in the environment. The default encoding is the same for both servers.
Other details regarding the code for generating the file and writing on file system:

File content is getting created in groovy with Markup builder. There is no XML declaration explicitly for this. Just added this line in the header <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

File is getting written with below code


     Path path = Paths.get(fileNameWithExtn);

     Files.write(path, xmlStr.getBytes());


Do notepad and notepad++ use the same font?

You could always use a hex entity or &pound; GB£ seems strange

You have shown XML / UTF-8 file but likely your Notepad++ charset set to ANSI when saved before. Bottom right click on charset and try "Convert to UTF-8" and save again should make it UTF-8. Notepad is probably working because it isn't reading as UTF-8

The fact that Notepad++ is showing xA3 means your file is not, in fact, a UTF-8 file.  Merely placing encoding="UTF-8" in the XML prolog doesn’t cause the content to be encoded as UTF-8.  Consider editing your question and showing us the code that generates that file.  I’m guessing you didn’t bother to specify a Charset when writing.

Actually, xA3 is the encoding of the pound sign when using ISO-8859-1 (or similar) encoding.

@VGR Yes it might not be the correct UTF-8 file but it working perfectly fine onlocal system so not sure about the correct issue . I have added more detail to the question regarding the code.

One thing you can do is to post a link to the actual file. That should sort it out

Wrong:  Files.write(path, xmlStr.getBytes());  Right:  Files.writeString(path, xmlStr);  Or, if you using a version of Windows older than 11: Files.write(path, xmlStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  getBytes() by itself will use the default charset of the system, in versions of Java older than 17.  On Windows, that’s usually a one-byte charset (for example, windows-1252 in American English versions of Windows).  Instead of hoping it will use the right charset, specify the charset explicitly so you can be certain.

Hehe I missed that ;)
